# How can a JAX-RS REST service have authentication handled by annotations?

Tags: java, authentication, rest, jersey, tomcat6

I have a REST api written with JAX-RS, and I need to add authentication to it. So far all the information I've been able to find about it has suggestions for doing it [via spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124831/how-to-do-rest-authentication-with-jax-rs), which I'm not using. Is there something already existing, or would it be easy to write, something that will let me annotate either a method, or the entire class which would force auth headers to be present?

I'm using tomcat6 and jersey, if that matters.

Something like:

```
@Path("api")
public class Api {
    @GET
    @AuthenticationRequired
    public Response getInfo(...) {...}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want `import javax.annotation.Security.RolesAllowed;`

The annotation itself looks like this

```
@Path("/helloworld")
@RolesAllowed({"ADMIN", "ORG1"})
public class helloWorld {

@GET
@Path("sayHello")  
@Produces("text/plain")
@RolesAllowed("ADMIN")
public String sayHello() {
   return "Hello World!";
}
}
```

Comment: Reference:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24983/secure.htm#BABGBJAC

Comment: How do I define what the roles are and how they provide authentication?

Comment: That's specific to the application.  Refer here for another Spring-less approach, defining them in web.xml http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncav.html

Comment: Thanks, I think the docs from your first comment should get me there. I guess I'm still not quite clear though - what do you mean by saying it's specific to the application? I don't know how to define them for the application. I see a @DeclareRoles annotation in the doc you linked,  but I don't see how to tell it how the roles authenticate. Is that done in the web.xml file?

Comment: So are you not presently implementing role based security?  Or do you have roles defined and just need to secure your RESTful URLs by the roles you already have?

Comment: Currently there's nothing at all relating to roles, or any security. I don't have any specific method in mind, just whatever will be reasonably secure and not too heavy to implement.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8837/discussion-between-derdc-and-daenyth)

Answer (score 3):

I would manage security at the container level.  Here's a good writeup if you happen to be using Apache CXF:

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/secure-jax-rs-services.html

And here's an example for Glassfish:

http://www.butonic.de/2010/06/18/a-simple-jax-rs-security-context-example-in-glassfish/

Here's one more link, which discusses JSR 250 annotations (e.g. @RolesAllowed):

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/twbs_jaxrs_impl_securejaxrs_annotations.html

Comment: Last link looks dead. Seems to be a link farm.

Comment: @Patrick M - You're right: it looks like "ericonjava" let his domain registration lapse.  Thank you for the "heads up".

Comment: Here's a [wayback link](https://web.archive.org/web/20110318205916/http://www.ericonjava.com/?p=325) to the article. Looks legit. Unfortunately, my service is using Dropwizard, so that's Jersey on Jetty instead of Tomcat. Anyways, have a +1.